# Does Dojo supports Ajax Pull mechanism?

Tags: dojo

I am new in Dojo framework. I just wanted to know if Dojo supports Ajax Pull concept and if yes, then please provide me the references of those.

Comment: Check out this link: http://cometd.org/

Comment: yes, I did search on this but everything comes with Ajax Push concept. I was looking for Ajax pull concept. both are different concepts. So, just wanted to know if we can perform Ajax pull with Dojo UI framework.

Answer (score 2):

You can make GET and POST calls using `dojo.xhr`.  You can schedule these using javascript's `setTimeout` function.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrGet.html

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/xhrPost.html

Comment: Thanks for your valuable inputs!! this really helps!! So, this will be supported in IE7 and 8 also? Actually, i need this functionality across all browsers like IE, firefox, chrome etc...

Comment: Supported browsers depends on the version of Dojo.  Here are the release notes for 1.7 http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/releasenotes/1.7.html